# importing variables across modules

Tags: python

Fairly new to python, have looked around on various so sources, but so far nothing has made the code actually function. The code I am using is **from file1 import x**. (have also tried **import file1.x**) but both of them make the module run rather than giving me the variable.
Is there any other code to use or am I missing something?

Comment: Python will always execute the code in an imported module. There's no way around this. This is how it correctly loads the code in the module. If you absolutely cannot have this behavior, use an external config file to store the variable value.

Comment: ANY form of import is going to "make the module run" - how else would the imported objects ever come into existence?  If you have code that you don't want to run when a module is imported (rather than run directly), the convention is to indent it in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that a module is evaluated when you import it, even if you import only one object.

So if you want to avoid this you can hide every running functions inside a statement like :

```
# in file1.py
x = 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    running_function(x)
    running_function2(x)
```

You can declare your variables freely, but you should wrap everything else inside functions or classes, and make the calls inside this special block.

Answer (score -1):

My file1.py has only following line,
x="hello world"

from file1 import x

print x actually printing the value from other file1